# Accessing to a ListView at runtime to update an item

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have to update a ListView **item** by clicking on a button. How do I find and update one at the runtime?

**update**: I mean I have to find the certain ListView item and update the text of this item only.

Comment: Depends on how you created your items. Added ListViewItems manually or bound to some item collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ListViewItems were added to the ListView manually, you can look them up by their content and replace with new content like this (using System.Linq):

```
object contentToReplace = ...;
object newContent = ...;
ListViewItem item = listView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().FirstOrDefault(
    lvi => lvi.Content == contentToReplace);
if (item != null)
{
    item.Content = newContent;
}
```

Comment: There're 2 columns in my listView. How do I add newListViewItem to specified column?

Comment: You should perhaps post some code and XAML. Otherwise it's really hard to guess what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You may use commands. For example:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static readonly ICommand ItemClickCommand = new RoutedCommand("ItemClick", typeof(MainWindow));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.CommandBindings.Add(
                new CommandBinding(
                    MainWindow.ItemClickCommand,
                    this.ExecuteItemClickCommand,
                    this.CanExecuteItemClickCommand));
        }

        private void CanExecuteItemClickCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = e.Parameter is ListBoxItem;
        }

        private void ExecuteItemClickCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Here you can access ListBoxItem that holds a clicked button.
            ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)e.Parameter;
            listBoxItem.Content = "...";
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the only thing you need is to assign ItemClickCommand to a button and bind CommandParameter to corresponding ListBoxItem.

XAML example:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem.Content>
                <Button Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ItemClickCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                        Content="Click Me"/>
            </ListBoxItem.Content>
    <...>
```